# ASP.NET Core HotChocolate HotChocolate.FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, fluentvalidation, hotchocolate

I am tying to validate my mutation input fields with HotChocolate.FluentValidation. Lookint at the example code, I do not have Argument on IInputObjectTypeDescriptor (descriptor).
I have tried the following.

I wrote my injector:

```
    public static class DependenciesInjector
        {
            public static void AddInjectableFluentValidationDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                IEnumerable<TypeInfo> classTypes = assembly.ExportedTypes.Select(t => IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(t))
                                                                         .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);
    
                foreach (TypeInfo type in classTypes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<TypeInfo> interfaces = type.ImplementedInterfaces.Select(i => i.GetTypeInfo());
    
                    foreach (TypeInfo handlerType in interfaces.Where(i => i.IsGenericType))
                    {
                        services.AddTransient(handlerType.AsType(), type.AsType());
                    }
                }
         

   }
    }
```

and used on service collection

```
services.AddInjectableFluentValidationDependencies();
services.AddTransient<IValidatorInterceptor, FluentvalidationInterceptor>();
```

Configured my GraphQL:

```
public static void ConfigureGraphQL(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                    .AddFluentValidation()
                    .ModifyOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultResolverStrategy = ExecutionStrategy.Serial;
                    })
                    .AddQueryType<Query>()
                    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                    .AddSubscriptionType<Subscription>()
                    .AddType<PlatformType>()
                    .AddType<AddPlatformInputType>()
                    .AddType<AddPlatformPayloadType>()
                    .AddType<CommandType>()
                    .AddType<AddCommandInputType>()
                    .AddType<AddCommandPayloadType>()
                    .AddFiltering()
                    .AddSorting()
                    .AddInMemorySubscriptions();
        }
```

and called it in the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureDbContext(Configuration);
            services.InjectContainerServices(Configuration);
            services.ConfigureGraphQL();
            services.AddFluentValidation(options =>
            {
                options.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = false;
                options.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
            });
        }
```

Wrote my validator class

```
public class AddPlatformInputValidator : AbstractValidator<AddPlatformInput>
{
    public AddPlatformInputValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(input => input.Name).NotEmpty()
                                    .WithMessage("Name is required.");
    }
}
```

Applied to input type record

```
public record AddPlatformInput([UseFluentValidation] string Name);
```

Applied it on input type class

```
public class AddPlatformInputType : InputObjectType<AddPlatformInput>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IInputObjectTypeDescriptor<AddPlatformInput> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Description("Represents the input to add for a platform.");

            descriptor.Field(x => x.Name)
                      .Type<StringType>()
                      //.Argument("input", argument => argument.UseFluentValidation()) //error .Argument not recognized
                      .Description("Represents the name for the platform.");

            base.Configure(descriptor);
        }
    }
```

Any idea what did I missed, or did wrong?
thnx